# Как синхронизировать доступ к переменным?

Tags: переменные, синхронизация, java

Можно сихронизировать доступ к переменным `count` и `count2` без использования синхронизированного метода?

```
public class Lasttask{
int count1;
int count2; 
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Lasttask lt = new Lasttask();
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
                lt.count1++;
                try {
                    sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                lt.count2++;
                System.out.println(lt.count1);
                System.out.println(lt.count2);
                System.out.println("");

            }
        }
    }.start();

    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
                lt.count1++;
                try {
                    sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                lt.count2++;
                System.out.println(lt.count1);
                System.out.println(lt.count2);
                System.out.println("");
            }

        }

    }.start();

}
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

Comment: А еще просто [Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) есть.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать синхронизированный блок кода:

```
synchronized(monitor) {
  lt.count++;
}
```

Либо использовать AtmoicInteger:

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

count.incrementAndGet();
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, тут поможет модификатор volatile.

Comment: @Евгений Карпов ошибаетесь, т.е. lt.count++ неатомарная операция.